# Cropping Image with Graphics in Visual Studio changes file type headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, jpeg, crop

I am trying to crop an Image and save it to the server. The problem I am having is that it appears that the cropping process I follow has a side-effect to the jpeg and jpg Images. 
The process-method I am trying is slightly different than the one I have found in numerous posts about cropping an image in asp.net because I am using a byte[] for the image.

```
    public static byte[] CropImage(byte[] imgBytes, Rectangle rec)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgBytes);
        Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);

        Bitmap croppedBmpImage = new Bitmap(200, 200);

        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(croppedBmpImage))
        {
            gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            gr.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200),
                rec,
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        byte[] result = (byte[]) converter.ConvertTo(croppedBmpImage, typeof(byte[]));
        croppedBmpImage.Dispose();

        return result;
    }
```

The image is cropped correctly without any preview issues in my computer. However I am using Alfresco to store the images and I see that the thumbnail preview inside the application doesn't work with the image. From what I saw this happens only to .jpg and .jpeg images. From what I read .jpg and .jpeg images store some metadata inside them that seem to be deleted from my cropped image. 
When I open the original .jpg or .jpeg image with notepad I notice it starts with some king of metadata details such as JFIF. (Ψΰ JFIF  H H  Ϋ „ )
On the other hand when I open with notepad a .png image I notice it starts with

```
‰PNG
```

My cropped image starts like that too after the cropping process. Is there any way to hold on the original metadata or crop an image as a .jpg file from the beginning or am I missing something else here?

Comment: So what will happen if you store image without cropping? Is it working correctly?

Comment: If I don't use the cropping process it works correctly yes. It doesn't lose any metadata and the image previews correctly in Alfresco.

Comment: Why would you _need_ to preserve that data, though? The image itself is cropped anyway, so that sure loses data.

Comment: I understand that data will be lost. I am asking if there is a way that this doesn't happen. If for example there is a different way-mechanism of cropping images and don't lose it's headers. Maybe there is some way of cropping specifically jpeg images. My main problem though is that in Alfresco the users can't view the jpeg image thumbnails. I can save them as .png since the cropping process seems to do that to the image and the thumbnail shows correctly but I am not sure if this is the best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two ways:

1. Save the byte[] as Jpeg image and then send the new bytes back to the user.
2. Create an empty Jpeg and then append the cropped bytes.

For the first option you can see an example:

```
    public static byte[] CropImage(byte[] imgBytes, Rectangle rec)
    {
        byte[] result = null;
        using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(imgBytes))
        {
            Image img = Image.FromStream(mStream);

            Bitmap croppedBmpImage = new Bitmap(200, 200);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(croppedBmpImage))
            {
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200),
                    rec,
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            result = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(croppedBmpImage, typeof(byte[]));

            using (MemoryStream jpegStream = new MemoryStream(result))
            {
                croppedBmpImage.Save(jpegStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                Image img1 = Image.FromStream(jpegStream);
                img1.Save(@"C:\Users\darellis\Desktop\image1.jpg");
            }

            croppedBmpImage.Dispose();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and it works but I was wondering if there is a way to alter the cropping image in a way that doesn't affect the .jpeg headers. I am guessing that since I create a Bitmap for my process the format is not taken into consideration and the final result is an image as simple as possible. However I would appreciate an explanation of the way the process works.

Comment: I don't think the standard .Net jpeg support is advanced enough to give the export all the original jpeg header data... or even to read it out of the original jpeg header.